# How to automatically sync photos from the Eye-fi import software to iPhoto on a Mac?

Tags: workflow, iphoto, macbook, eye-fi

I bought an eye-fi SD card to enable wifi upload of the photos from my non wifi capable camera. It works fine.

My trouble starts in the postprocessing part of my workflow. To use eye-fi one has to install its own software. Images and videos are uploaded using that software to a different location and database than iPhoto. Therefore I have 2 photo databases on my laptop.

Is there a way to automatically synchronize/move the media files from the eye-fi database to iphoto?

I use the macos version of the eye-fi software on a macbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Eye-Fi web site: [Folder Management](http://support.eye.fi/software/account/folder-management/)

In the Eye-Fi Center software click the "settings" icon next to the Eye-Fi Card icon and choose "Photos" then under "Manage" choose "iPhoto" from the dropdown.

[image]